# Is there a Firefox extension to record and playback clicks on a web page?

Tags: firefox, recording

I need this tool to automate JavaScript testing.

[Selenium Recorder](http://seleniumrecorder.mozdev.org/) used to work, but is no longer available.

Comment: Please define what are "still available" clicks?

Comment: This used to work,but now it's not available:http://seleniumrecorder.mozdev.org/

Answer (score 1):

Web Developer Tools and Firebug offer developer and tester tools for web pages (and sites).

But if you want to track what has been clicked on a page, using Greasemonkey to inject a script which hooks into clickable items, and records what has been clicked might be a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

[iOpus](http://www.iopus.com/) iMacros are very good and flexible IMO. I remember bulk downloading pictures from an AJAX page with it (using the "torrent version", since it's really expensive), it's quite a hard task and it made it without giving me too much headache.

Answer (score 1):

Use Selenium IDE, http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/ 
"Selenium IDE is an integrated development environment for Selenium tests. It is implemented as a Firefox extension, and allows you to record, edit, and debug tests. Selenium IDE includes the entire Selenium Core, allowing you to easily and quickly record and play back tests in the actual environment that they will run.

Selenium IDE is not only recording tool: it is a complete IDE. You can choose to use its recording capability, or you may edit your scripts by hand. With autocomplete support and the ability to move commands around quickly, Selenium IDE is the ideal environment for c reating Selenium tests no matter what style of tests you prefer."